# RSpec test suite - Share huge object across all specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, testing, rspec

I have quite a big Rails 6 system with around 150 models.
Most of them belong to a huge model (Community), which is the core of the system.

When running RSpec (3.6.0), every model needs to be initialized/created and for that, the creation of a Community is required. That creation takes around 3 seconds for every spec, since Community has a lot of callbacks after create, and that ends up being a lot of lost time in between tests.

We're using `use_transactional_fixtures`,  but I'm not sure this matters at all. since I believe even without it, every factory will instance a new community anyway.

I was wondering if there's any way with RSpec for us to share one community across the whole test suite, and let all the factories use that one, instead of rollbacking and creating a new one for every spec. Since the Community has its own spec anyway, and in that one we check it's creation and stuff.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While its possible you need to consider the potential for lingering state between tests which causes unreliable and flappy tests. Is it possible you could solve part of the issue through stubbing?

Comment: That's possible for sure, but i guess i'll have to test it out if i find a way to share a single community across all tests.